# Change Magento Invoice PDF Header

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I need to change the Magento default pdf Header from "*Invoice n 201700009 - Invoice date 06/01/2017*" to "*Receipt n 201700009 - Receipt date 06/01/2017*".

I think that the file is the following:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

I have tried to replace the string 'invoice' on line 108:

```
$this->_beforeGetPdf();
$this->_initRenderer('invoice');
```

And the following string on line 133:

```
$this->insertDocumentNumber(
    $page,
    Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId()
);
```

But nothing change in the printed invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
It was pretty easy, just override this inside:

```
code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

Comment: what will be for Magento 2? it's not working for Magento 2. how can i override the same invoice.php file ?

Comment: I never used magento 2. Try to ask a new question!

Comment: @WaqasShakeel Did you get any solution?

Comment: @zus i sorted the issue that time but don't remember now as its 3 years old thread. Sorry